# zuul gateway send wrong redirect_uri using keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul, gateway

I'm using zuul gateway on `my.domain.com` and authorization code grant type to authenticate requests with keycloak on `auth-my.domain.com`
when gateway redirects to the keycloak for login
redirect-uri is `gateway:8080/...` instead of `my.domain.com/...`
and after logging in i will redirect to `gateway:8080/...`
what should I do to gateway sends the correct url to the keycloak?

Comment: Hi, do you mind sharing your application.properties/yml file? I have recently implemented something similar, so i could try to help.

Comment: Hi, Yeah of course. Here is my config for authorization server

`spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: myClientId
            client-secret: myClientSecret
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://auth-my.domain.com/auth/realms/myRealm`

Comment: Okay. So, if i am not wrong you are trying to access the REST APIs of keycloak and not its portal. What i mean is, on detecting that a user is not logged in, do you want an error as the response or do you want to redirect the user to the keycloak portal?

Comment: I want to redirect user to the keycloak login page.

Comment: I guess i confused your problem for some other problem. Did you add the resource URI to the valid resource uri field? This is usually the cause of invalid parameter redirect_uri error.

Comment: Yes id did that. I think my main problem is that gateway in docker environment has wrong host name. But I couldn't fix it.